# How to get original types before auto-boxing?

Tags: java

Java auto-boxes ellipsis Object arguments. How can I tell if an argument is actually primitive before auto-boxing?

```
static void foo(Object...args)
{
    System.out.println(args[0].getClass());
}

foo(1);
foo(new Integer(1));
```

output:

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Since the autoboxing takes place before the method is executed, you can't find that out inside the method.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.  Long answer: you caaaaaaaaaan't.

Comment: I don't know if such primitive type as int have a method ``getClass`` anyway.

Comment: @Aero there are `Class` objects for primitive types visible in the wrapper classes, here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE . But as already noted the actual argument here is `Integer` and not `int`.

Comment: That is what I expected. I just wanted to make sure it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot detect wether the arguement was boxed from a primitive type as you already get Objects as parameters to the method which means the auto-boxing already happens before the method.

Additionally you cannot perform ".getClass" on a primitive type.